# Understanding the use of 'this' when passing object to modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am implementing a modal `service` as used [here](http://codepen.io/julianpaulozzi/pen/wBgpjM?editors=101) and [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-modal-service-with-extras/15357) and I don't understand the use of `vm`

On line 13 there is `var vm = this;` and then uses `vm.`. Does this make them a model and expose them to the `$scope`?

I am trying to pass and object to the modal that will change every time the modal opens. I have previously been doing by setting the object as a `$scope` variable.

To open the modal I am using this code:

```
$scope.openExercise = function(exercise) {
    $scope.activeExercise = exercise;
    myModals.openExercise(exercise)
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log()
        }, function(err) {
            alert(err);
        });
};
```

and `console.log` shows my full object however it is not displayed in the modal where I am trying to display it as {{exercise.name}} etc etc...

My first question is regarding the use of `var vm = this;` and secondly, how do I bind / pass my object for displaying in my modal?

Many thanks.

EDIT - Added Modal Code

```
<ion-content class="has-subheader has-footer" lazy-scroll delegate-handle="modalContent">
    <ion-slide-box ng-init="updateSlider()" ng-show="showimage" on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" class="exercise-slider-slides" does-continue="false" auto-play="false" show-pager="true">
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="sliderimage in activeExercise.images track by $index">
            <div ng-if="isNumber(sliderimage)" class="modalSliderThumbnail" style="background-image:url(http://.s3.amazonaws.com/medium/{{sliderimage}}.jpg)"></div>
            <div ng-if="!isNumber(sliderimage)" class="modalSliderThumbnail" style="background-image:url({{sliderimage}})"></div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
    <ion-list can-swipe="true" ng-hide="showimage">
        <form>
            <!--                 <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label energized">Title (Tap to edit)</span>
                <input type="text" class="title-input" placeholder="" initial-value ng-model="activeExercise.exerciseName"></input>
            </label> -->
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label energized">Description (Tap to edit)</span>
                <textarea placeholder="Tap to add a Description" initial-value ng-model="activeExercise.exerciseDescription"></textarea>
            </label>
        </form>
        <ion-item ng-click="showPopup()" class="item-icon-right param-button">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-plus-outline"></i> <span class="energized">Tap to add Variables</span>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="param in activeExercise.Params track by $index" ng-click="showPopup(param)">
            <strong>{{param.param}}</strong> : {{param.childParam}}
            <ion-option-button class="ion-minus-circled assertive button-options" ng-click="deleteParam(param)"></ion-option-button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button class="button button-block button-gradient icon-right ion-ios-plus-outline add-to-programme-button" ng-click="addExerciseToProgramme(activeExercise, programme);showimage=true" ng-hide="showimage">Add to {{programme.programmeTitle}}</button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: `var vm = this; ` is used when using the "controller as" syntax.

Comment: So how can I pass to and display my object in my modal?

Comment: where are you trying to call this from?

Comment: It's called from my View (button) where I pass the object from. View and Modal are the same controller. However I would like to use a service as I have lots of different modals from different controllers and the service makes things a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"vm = this" -> this is used to prevent any issues with this scoping  (i.e. closures in nested functions) e.g. if you have the following in your controller:

```
var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
var log = [];
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
    this.push(key + ': ' + value);
}, log);
expect(log).toEqual(['name: misko', 'gender: male']);
```

You see that "this" has another meaning in the inner function than outside. So setting vm to this in the beginning of your controller allows you to safely reference your scope using vm.

In order to answer your second question, you'll need to post the code of the controller you use for the modal.

Comment: @pherris, benohead is correct. I have now added the modal code.

Comment: If your controller referenced in your HTML code as:
`ng-controller="BlablaCtrl as xyz"`
then you need to use `xyz.activeExercise` instead of `activeExercise`. You are basically accessing the activeExercise variable from the controller scope in your modal.